# How to use variable in variable to define php function and later echo it

Tags: php, function, echo

I am trying to use variable in variable function, then to do some calculations and later use that variable and print out answer:

```
    <?php

$a($b)=function() {

if ($b == 10 ) {
    return 10 ;
}else{
    return 20 ;

     }
}

$a(10);
echo $a(10);

?>
```

I am getting error:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Comment: `function() {` <- Put the parameters between those parentheses.

Comment: @Rizier123 I will try

Comment: You may want to read about php functions https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `$a($b)` means `invoking a function` instead of `declaration`. you should define `$a` and pass `$b` as a variable to the function.

**Change this to:**

```
$a($b)=function() {
```

**This:**

```
$a=function($b) {
```

**Whole PHPcode**  [**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/781100)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$a = function($b)
{

    if ($b == 10)
    {
        return 10;
    } else
    {
        return 20;
    }
};

echo $a(10);
?>
```

Comment: @NotsoPr0 Welcome ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

**$a($b)=function() {**

to

**$a=function($b) {**